# Pyspark delete multiple columns after join Programmatically

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

```
columnToDelete=[empDFTems2.name,empDFTems.gender]

listjoin = empDFTems.join(empDFTems2, (empDFTems["emp_id"]==empDFTems2["emp_id"]), "left").drop(*columnToDelete)
```

It wont take the list since its a dataframe name.
How can i programmatically drop all columns for the given dataframe after the join, reading which column to drop from the list

Comment: According to the documentation it should work with list of string. That might is the case why your call is not working. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.drop.html?highlight=drop#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.drop

Comment: trying to make it work with a list of df.names instead of just list of strings since it would delete columns with similar names from the joined dataframe

Comment: `drop()` can take both string names and actual columns as in your case. What error are you getting?

Comment: If you look at the code snipped .drop(*columnToDelete) Im having trouble doing this .drop(*columnToDelete)
where columns to delete is a list of dataframe columns names 0


columnToDelete=[empDFTems2.name,empDFTems.gender]

Answer (score 1):

According to PySpark doc you can only pass list of col names as strings. if you want to pass a column object only a single value is taken .

> drop(*cols)
>
> Returns a new DataFrame that drops the specified column. This is a
> no-op if schema doesn’t contain the given column name(s).
>
> Parameters:   **cols – a string name of the column to drop**, or **a Column to
> drop**, or a list of string name of the columns to drop.

I would suggest to select the required columns rather dropping the unnecessary ones. select accepts list of column objects so it should work fine.

```
empDFTems.show()
+------+-------+------+---+-----+
|emp_id|   name|gender|age| dept|
+------+-------+------+---+-----+
|     1| alis R|     F| 34|   IT|
|     2|Robin M|     M| 44|Sales|
+------+-------+------+---+-----+

empDFTems2.show()
+------+-----+------+-------+------+
|emp_id| name|gender|country|active|
+------+-----+------+-------+------+
|     1| alis|Female|     34|    IT|
|     2|Robin|  Male|     44| Sales|
+------+-----+------+-------+------+

#columnToDelete=[empDFTems2.name,empDFTems.gender]
#lets take delete columns separately if possible 
empDFTems2columnToDelete = ["name"]
empDFTemscolumnToDelete = ["gender"]

selectCols = [empDFTems[i] for i in empDFTems.columns if i not in empDFTemscolumnToDelete] + [empDFTems2[i] for i in empDFTems2.columns if i not in empDFTemscolumnToDelete]

listjoin = empDFTems.join(empDFTems2, (empDFTems["emp_id"]==empDFTems2["emp_id"]), "left").select(selectCols)

listjoin.show()

+------+-------+---+-----+------+------+-------+------+
|emp_id|   name|age| dept|emp_id|gender|country|active|
+------+-------+---+-----+------+------+-------+------+
|     1| alis R| 34|   IT|     1|Female|     34|    IT|
|     2|Robin M| 44|Sales|     2|  Male|     44| Sales|
+------+-------+---+-----+------+------+-------+------+
```

Alternatively if you must use drop, then the only option is looping over the columns

```
columnToDelete=[empDFTems2.name,empDFTems.gender]
listjoin = empDFTems.join(empDFTems2, (empDFTems["emp_id"]==empDFTems2["emp_id"]), "left")
for i in columnToDelete:
    listjoin = listjoin.drop(i)
    
listjoin.show()
+------+-------+---+-----+------+------+-------+------+
|emp_id|   name|age| dept|emp_id|gender|country|active|
+------+-------+---+-----+------+------+-------+------+
|     1| alis R| 34|   IT|     1|Female|     34|    IT|
|     2|Robin M| 44|Sales|     2|  Male|     44| Sales|
+------+-------+---+-----+------+------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Nice. Yeah I was interested in the loop one, since its working. My only question is how does it have the dataframe column context after the join? I know spark does lazy evaluation, but was curious to know how solid this would work? 
I dont want it unexpectedly dropping columns which it isnt supposed to